# Задача по спискам python

Tags: python

[image: сама задача]

Создал необходимые списки, но не понимаю как провести действия над элементами.

```
f = [7, 19, 92, 22, 1, 29, 99, 192]
d = [82, 91, 33, 2, 89, 54, 55, 3]
r = sum(f)
```

Comment: Показывайте имеющийся код. Например, правая часть выражения может считаться как  s=sum(f). Да, формула , конечно, нехорошо записана, ,i переиспользуется в разных смыслах

Comment: **f = [7, 19, 92, 22, 1, 29, 99, 192]
d = [82, 91, 33, 2, 89, 54, 55, 3]
r = sum(f)**

Comment: Вопрос отредактируйте, код в комментах нечитаемый

Comment: Сделал редактирование

Comment: Формула всё же странная. Не может быть `i` и слева индексом и у суммы переменной. Неоднозначная какая-то формула получается. Либо у суммы другой индекс должен быть, например `j`, либо я чего-то не понимаю.

Comment: @CrazyElf, нотация позволяет занимать *i* под индекс в сумме. Обычно так не делают, но в данном случае *i* внутри суммы и *i* вне - два разных индекса.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Ладно. Но выглядит это плоховато )  Лучше когда разные всё же обозначения.

Answer (score 3):

```
c=[r*(f[i]-2.5)/d[i] for i in range(8)]
```

Comment: `c = [r * (fi - 2.5) / di for fi, di in zip(f, d)]`.